# How to split a column with tuple into two column, pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
dummy_df = pd.DataFrame([],columns=['ab'])
dummy_df['ab'] = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]

def dummy_func(x):
    return x[0], x[1]
dummy_df.loc[:['a','b']] = dummy_df['ab'].apply(lambda x: dummy_func(x))
```

I have a dataframe in which I have a column with a tuple, and I want to split it into two columns, can anyone help me. I tried with above code but it gives error. I want to learn if I can do it in one line.

Answer (score 1):

Simple just convert the column to list

```
dummy_df[['a', 'b']] = list(dummy_df['ab'])
```

---

```
       ab  a  b
0  (1, 2)  1  2
1  (3, 4)  3  4
2  (5, 6)  5  6
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str` accessor:

```
dummy_df['a'] = dummy_df['ab'].str[0]
dummy_df['b'] = dummy_df['ab'].str[1]
print(dummy_df)

# Output
       ab  a  b
0  (1, 2)  1  2
1  (3, 4)  3  4
2  (5, 6)  5  6
```

The slow way in one line:

```
dummy_df[['a', 'b']] = dummy_df['ab'].apply(pd.Series)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
dummy_df = pd.DataFrame({'ab': [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]})
dummy_df[['a', 'b']] = dummy_df['ab'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x[0], x[1]]))
```